# HTML Form on Submit, redirect to a page depending on Radio button value selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I want to be able to on form Submit, redirect to a page depending on Radio Button value selected.

I've read up on similar solutions but my special case here is that I need to pass the input values onto the URL as well.

For Example:

(1) Start on the Form page with this URL (http://example.com/?cat=1)

(2) Select the Radio Button Field (value="999" will put "page123" or if value=888 then put "page456" into the URL) and click Submit (also 'gets' the "cat" hidden input value)

(3) Redirects to URL ---> (http://example.com/page123/?cat=1)

Form page:

```
<form action="<MY DESIRED URL ON STEP 3>" method="get">
<input name="cat" type="hidden" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="third-row"><input id="1" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="999" />
  <div class="third-row"><input id="2" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="888" />
  <div class="third-row"><input id="3" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="777" />
</div>
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="GO!" />
</form>
```

Comment: **What have you tried??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a switch statement so that you can set your URL based on the value of the input. Then use one header statement to redirect.

```
switch($_GET['styleid']){
    case "999":
        $url = "destinationURL";
        $params = "?cat='.$_GET['cat'].'";
        break;
    case "899":
        $url = "destinationURL";
        $params = "?cat='.$_GET['cat'].'";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
if (isset($url) && isset($params)){
    header("location: ".$url.$params);
    die();
}
else{
    die('error');
}
```

Edit: To answer your question about getting the cat value into the next page:

In your form modify your hidden input:

```
<input name="cat" type="hidden" value="<?php echo  trim(strip_tags($_GET['cat'])); ?>" />
```

Then see edits above for setting the param.

Edit 2: After seeing your code, you are directing your form action to the same page and putting the processor inside a  tag which will not work.

Update your form to direct to a new PHP file that you create. Example: "form-handler.php" located in a folder called "processors"

```
<form action="/processors/form-handler.php" method="GET" target="self"></form>
```

Place the switch statement and header redirect into the processor file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how do I set value1 = "input value of cat" ? Is it like value1 = $_GET['cat'] ?

Comment: So if you start on example.com/?cat=1 you need to be able to keep that value on the next page?

Comment: see my edits and let me know if that clears it up for you.

Comment: Its better but it seems its still not getting to the page I want. Im actually using wordpress to make this website so Im dont think its reading the php script correctly, i think it only reads scripts in js? If I do this statically by putting the action link like this,  <form action="http://test.ascension.systems/product/ring-style1-example/" method="get">, then I get to where I want which is "http://test.ascension.systems/product/ring-style1-example/?productid=2095&styleid=888". But I want the "ring-style1-example" part to change dynamically depending on selection of radio button :(

Comment: Are you sending the form to a script that is not a wordpress generated file? That is what I would do. Do you know the actual url's of the locations and can put them in the switch statement?

Comment: Im kinda new to this so Im not exactly sure whats a wordpress generate file. Do you mean the functions.php file? If so, how do I do it? Yep, I put in the correct ones. but its still not working.This is what I have so far.. https://imgur.com/a/TAGcE

Comment: It looks like you are submitting the form to the same page and then you put my code in a <script> tag which would be javascript. That wont work. I suggest you make a new PHP file name it whatever you want and put it in a folder of it's own.Then put the php switch code with the header redirect. in the form action direct it to this new php file.